# Please help ID my bike. When I got it it was just a frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

No original parts. Got as just frame.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Most likely Chinese.

Comment: We need more information, although its pretty generic. Age (Its anything from mid1990's to mid 2010's), Country it was bought etc.  You need to match unique features - bottom tube/headtube gusset and  dropouts might help.   Chances of a ID even with that information are slim  to none.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - there is absolutely nothing distinctive about that frame that could show it as being anything.

The likely source is an eastern factory, but what brand it was originally really doesn't matter.  You've clearly built it up with parts to a rideable completeness, and the workmanship and wear on those components is of more value than a name.

If you absolutely must have a decal on it, there's nothing wrong with naming it an "Eric Bike" because you've done just as much work as trek or raleigh or schwinn would do.

Personally "Long Green Meanie" sounds like a fine name for your bike.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I’ll take the name into consideration! Lol